# How to write constraint involving a certain parameter in clingo?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo, clasp, gringo

I am attempting to solve the Google ASP Competition 2019 : Insurance Referee Assignment problem. The problem is provided in [this link](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.unical.it%2F%7Edodaro%2Faspchallenge2019%2Finsurancereferees.package.zip&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFASBm6qql9jPEm4hfjLmGmR-LCXg).

There is a hard constraint that if a referee has preference type of 0 then the case will not be assigned to that referee. I have simplified the problem to include a few variables.

`case(cid)` refers to a case with cid as the case id.
`ref(rid)` refers to the referee with referee id.

`pref(rid, type)` takes the preference of referee 'rid' and type which takes value from 0 to 3. The higher the number, the more likely it will take the case.

In `ref(10, 3)` and `ref(9, 2)`, the higher preference will be given to `ref(10)`.

I have tried the following clingo code:

```
ref(rid).
case(cid).
pref(rid, type).

assign(cid, rid) :- ref(rid), pref(rid, type), type != 0.

case(4).

ref(3).
ref(5).

pref(3, 0).
pref(5, 1).

#show assign/2.
```

However, when I run the command, it shows satisfiable but outputs only this

```
assign(cid, rid)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In clingo variables start with a capital letter and are "valid" just withhin the rule. So my guess is you want the following code:

```
assign(Rcid, Rrid) :- case(Rcid), ref(Rrid), pref(Rrid, Rtype), Rtype != 0.

case(4).    
ref(3).    ref(5).
pref(3, 0).    pref(5, 1).
#show assign/2.
```

output:

```
Solving...
Answer: 1
assign(4,5)
SATISFIABLE
```

Please note that only renaming the constants to variable names will result in an error message, you have to add `case(Rcid)` to the rule body as well. Variable names were freely choosen, you can use any variable name as long as it starts with a capital letter.